# rpmbuild: how to skip generation of "debuginfo" packages (without change SPEC file ; neither .rpmmacros)

Tags: rpmbuild

We need to (re)generated third party packages on **EL7** but we don't want to change SPEC file as suggested (`%define debug_package %{nil}` https://www.redhat.com/archives/shrike-list/2003-April/msg00069.html) and neither changing the `~/.rpmmacros` file as it is on a shared box for RPM build.

Is there any way to solve this via command line (additional parameter) with `rpmbuild`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After many tests I found the solution. In fact, it is possible to define `debug_package` outside of the SPEC file, using `--define`. Which gives:

```
rpmbuild --define "debug_package %{nil}" -ba SPECS/original.spec
```

Result is: I don't modify the third party SPEC file and no RPM `-debuginfo` is generated.

Comment: AFAICT, this method doesn't work at all, any more.  You cannot override this macro in the spec file or on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

`rpmbuild --rebuild --nodebuginfo file.src.rpm` -- this still generates debuginfo rpms

Another solution:

```
cat /etc/rpm/macros 
%debug_package %{nil}
```

Comment: This option works, as of today.